# React rendering trello card names

Tags: reactjs, trello

I have a react app which has a component as such:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/TrelloCards.css';

class TrelloCards extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const authenticationFailure = () => { console.log('Auth failure') };
    const trello = window.Trello;

    const getCards = () => {
      const error = (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    const cards = (cards) => {
      console.log(cards);
    }
    trello.get('/member/me/cards', cards, error);
  }

  trello.authorize({
      type: 'redirect',
      name: 'React Trello',
      scope: {
        read: 'true',
        write: 'true' },
      expiration: 'never',
      success: getCards,
      error: authenticationFailure,
      response_type: 'token',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <h1>Placeholder</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default TrelloCards;
```

I've successfully console logged my cards, but now I want to render them on the page, I've tried

```
render() {
  return(
    <ul>
      {cards}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I've tried mapping through cards like:

```
cards.map(card => {
  return(
    <li>{card.name}</li>
  );
}
```

But I get the error that 'cards' is not defined. I'm pretty new to React and programming in general, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `render` does not have access to the `cards` you downloaded through trello (they are only accessible within `componentDidMount`). One way to get around this is to save the downloaded cards to the react state. `render` will then be invoked because the state changed and the cards will be rendered.

#### Example

```
class TrelloCards extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      cards: []      <-------- define your initial state
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const trello = window.Trello;

    trello.authorize({
      type: 'redirect',
      name: 'React Trello',
      scope: {
        read: 'true',
        write: 'true' },
      expiration: 'never',
      success: () => console.log('auth success'),
      error: () => console.log('auth failure'),
      response_type: 'token',
    });

    trello.get('/member/me/cards', 
      (cards) => this.setState({ cards }),
                      ^----  set state here (shorthand)
      (error) => console.log('could not get cards'))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.cards.map(card =>
          <li>{card.name}</li>)}
          ^---- render cards from state
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked thanks! There's a missing ')' after the console.log('could not get cards') but apart from that it's all good.

Comment: Fixed it. Good catch.